# fetch response stream manipulation

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

Within a service worker, I want to inject HTML into the HTTP response body:

When returning a cached HTML response, I want to annotate the `<html>` element (e.g. turning `<html lang="en">` into  `<html data-origin="cache" lang="en">`) while streaming the original response before and after.

I have tried implementing this based on [Jake Archibald's streams fawning](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/streams-ftw/), but couldn't get anything to work. In the example below, I would imagine `injectHTML` to return a wrapper that transforms a part of the original stream - but I have no idea how to get there. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```js
addEventListener("fetch", async event => {
    let request = event.request;
    if(request.method !== "GET" ||
            !request.headers.get("Accept").includes("text/html")) {
        return;
    }

    let response = await fetch(request);
    let stream = injectHTML(response.body);
    response = new Response(stream);
    event.respondWith(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jake's [streams *explainer*](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/streams-ftw/), and the examples it contains, is a great starting point.

The most relevant example is the one that, erm... [replaces "cloud" with "butt"](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/transform-stream/).

The service worker code, along with a few caveats, [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/jakearchibald/isserviceworkerready/blob/master/src/demos/transform-stream/sw.js).

For the sake of completeness, here's the relevant service worker code that handles the replacement, but I'd recommend checking out the full source code in context.

```js
function replaceResponse(response, bufferSize, match, replacer) {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  let bufferStr = '';

  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    pull: controller => {
      return reader.read().then(result => {
        if (result.done) {
          controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(bufferStr));
          controller.close();
          return;
        }

        const bytes = result.value;
        bufferStr += decoder.decode(bytes, {stream: true});

        // this is the end of the final replacement in the FINAL string
        let lastReplaceEnds = 0;
        let replacedLengthDiff = 0;
        bufferStr = bufferStr.replace(match, (...args) => {
          const matched = args[0];
          // offset is the offset in the original string, hence replacedLengthDiff
          const offset = args[args.length - 2];
          const replacement = replacer(...args);

          replacedLengthDiff += replacement.length - matched.length;
          lastReplaceEnds = offset + matched.length + replacedLengthDiff;
          return replacement;
        });

        const newBufferStart = Math.max(bufferStr.length - bufferSize, lastReplaceEnds);
        controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(bufferStr.slice(0, newBufferStart)));
        bufferStr = bufferStr.slice(newBufferStart);
      });
    },
    cancel: () => {
      reader.cancel();
    }
  });

  return new Response(stream, {
    headers: response.headers
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this now works for me! Not entirely sure what I was doing wrong before, but perhaps I just got lost in the unfamiliarity of it all. Looks like I'll need a lot less code for my example too, which means I'm starting to recognize all the moving parts.
PS: Of course my description of Jake's article was intended to convey nothing but the utmost respect; it had me fawning too!